# ReactJs with Firebase, do I need to store user credentials/token in a local storage?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-router

So I want to create a protected route for my app and I read this post [Protected Route With Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505665/protected-route-with-firebase). Some how I didn't see any usage of local storage or cookies. I have created protected route with my custom jwt+Spring before  and I checked the token (if it exists on the local storage). I wonder if firebase library automatically set the local storage for me so I don't have to worry about it otherwise the credentials will be reset after user reload/refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase auth persists the authentication in local storage by default, and it will automatically re-authenticate if possible when the user returns to the page. The re-authentication is asynchronous, so you may need to set up your routing logic so it waits until you get your first callback from [onAuthStateChange](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authonauthstatechanged) before deciding whether to allow the user into the route, or do something else. (EDIT: I checked out the post you linked and it does wait, like my suggestion )

For more information on persisting auth state, see this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I checked on the storage tab and I found that firebase automatically store the authUser object which is pretty good!